# Android maps - Updated favorite cluster marker item icon overlaps with the old one

Tags: android, kotlin, google-maps

I've implemented a Maps UI with a cluster that contains items with different icons.
I have the ability to make an item "favorite" or not. The issue is that when I mark the item as favorite AND if the map is rendering the old item set, I get an overlapping item.

1. I enter the map screen and click an item
   [image]
2. As soon as I click the "favorite" icon from the bottomsheet, I re-update the specific item with the new property : isFavorite = true then I reload all the map items as following

```
 fun addItems(newItems: List<PlaceEntity>) {
        clearItems()
        addItems(newItems)
        cluster()
    }
```

I use a custom cluster manager class to handle this behavior :

```
class MapsClusterManager(
    context: Context,
    private val map: GoogleMap
) : ClusterManager<PlaceEntity>(context, map) {

    private var listener: MapsListener? = null
    private var clusterRenderer: MapsClusterRenderer? = null

    init {
        clusterRenderer = MapsClusterRenderer(context, map, this)
        renderer = clusterRenderer
        algorithm = NonHierarchicalDistanceBasedAlgorithm()

        map.setOnMarkerClickListener(this)
        setOnClusterItemClickListener { place ->
            listener?.onClusterItemClick(place)
            true
        }
    }

    fun setListener(mapsListener: MapsListener) {
        listener = mapsListener
    }

    fun add(newItems: List<PlaceEntity>) {
        clearItems()
        addItems(newItems)
        cluster()
    }

    fun animateCamera(latLng: LatLng?, zoomLevel: Float = 15f) {
        map.animateCamera(latLng, zoomLevel)
    }

    interface MapsListener {
        fun onClusterItemClick(placeEntity: PlaceEntity)
    }
}
```

The way I change the updated item is as following :

```
fun updateItem(newItem : Place){
 viewModelScope.launch {

            places.firstOrNull { it.id == newItem.id }?.let { item ->
                places.remove(item)
                places.add(newItem)

                _mapsUiState.emit(MapsUiState.Places(places.toList()))
   }
}
```

3. After clicking the favorite icon, updating the new data set and sending a new event to the map, the icon updates but after a second the old icon will appear on the map, overlapping the new icon.

[image]

What I've tried:

1. I've tried to remove the old marker using the cluster manager and adding a new one - didn't work.
2. I've tried to modify the equals and the hashcode methods hoping that the cachedMarkerCollection will recognise some changes - didn't work.
3. I thought that's it's something related to the fact that the map has started to render the markers and the update item call is faster, so I thought that the clearItems doesn't affect the updated item.

P.S. - It's a quite large item collection, 1000+ items so I think that the rendering is quite powerful.